# SMS service in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

We have an application which is in PowerBuilder 11.5 and we have to implement Short Message Services in our application.

What are all the things we need to have for this requirement?

I searched in google around early 2009 and I got free sms service which was enabled in one site using WSDL, also I deployed proxy object to our PBL and that time it was working. But now it is not working..

For example I have a site Jawalbsms or way2sms (sms site) how can I get that WSDL file from here or How can we create wsdl file for these sites.

Regards,
Ambat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally get the WSDL from the company that runs the service. Frequently the WSDL is at the same URI as the `targetNamespace`. For example http://example.com/wsdl/MyService.wsdl. This is just a common way to let people get the WSDL. Nothing needs to be at that URI. The sites you gave make money by showing advertisements to people who send SMS. I don't think they will let you send messages from your program. A trouble with any free service is that free services have a bad tendency to go away without warning. If your program is for business use I suggest you look for a paid service. If your program is for your own use or to help others you have to make a decision if it is OK for your program to stop working without warning till you can find another service. In addition you should think about the value of your time to find another service. In my own case I made the decision a number of years ago that free email services and free web hosting were more trouble than the value I got from them.

Answer (score 0):

May be now you might got the service provider I don't Know about the free service provider but you will definitely get the api from the venders.

I really don't understand that you are in search of Vendor or How to send send SMS from PowerBuilder applicaiton. I posted this on Yahoo PB Forum but now i have little bit improved code I customised it for Mvayoo and SMS Country.